# TextView alignment in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

In my cardFragment, inside my Main Activity, I have these type of cards that show some country examples and their respective name. As you can see, the TextView with their name changes place according to the country name's lenght. What can I do to make the TextView locked to a left and Bottom position? [Click here to see the image, please!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2XwH.gif)

[image]

This is my XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFotoPais"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPaisNome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.353"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgFotoPais"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-Put the following attribute in your TextView.

> android:gravity:- for setting the gravity of the contents of the View.
>
> android:layout_gravity:- for setting the gravity of the View or Layout relative to its parent Layout.

Comment: So I need to put both of them inside my <TextView> ?

Comment: as per the requirement you should go for it.

Comment: I can't seem to put `android:layout_gravity:` inside my <TextView>. It just stays in that red error color. By the way, the `android_gravity` should be "Left" if I want int locked to the left?

Comment: you may also use more than 1 value for gravity using pipeline like this  android:layout_gravity:Left | Bottom.

Comment: I need 15 rep to upvote :c It says that my vote is still casted tho

Comment: Yup go for it buddy

Comment: upvoted because it explains the difference on what you can achieve between the two unlike other answers i came across. I wondered why android:gravity would never centre the view but its android:layout_gravity is what i needed all along